# Como imprimir um double com 4 casas após o ponto em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, formatação, double

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double area, raio , pi;
    pi = 3.14159;       
    raio = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    area = pi * Math.Pow(raio,2);
    Console.WriteLine("A={0}\n",area.ToString("N0"));
}
```

O valor de entrada é 2.00 e o valor de saída esperado é 12.5664; entretanto, o que está saindo é 125.664. Como consigo corrigir isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer 4 casas não pode usar 0. Fiz de uma forma que evitar quebrar a aplicação por digitação errada e usando o que a linguagem já oferece:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var raio)) WriteLine($"A = {PI * Pow(raio, 2):N4}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZPaUra). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hC7FFP). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Formating.cs).